# Regex Negate non-contiguous Pattern

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, negation

I want to match the word **fleece** where it is **NOT** followed (either immediately, or further on) by the word **snow**

Input data:

```
Mary had a little lamb, its fleece was white as snow balls
```

The following regex's don't work as they all match, and shouldn't. I'm sure I have achieved this in the past but can't find where.

```
/(fleece).*(?!snow)/
/(fleece)[\w ]+(?!snow)/
```

For information, this regex is going to be part of a larger regex, and will be an alternation section, so I can't simply negate the whole regex - e.g.

```
/something(?!somethingelse)|fleece.*(?!snow)/
```

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there . Put `.*` inside the negative lookahead. The below regex would capture the string `fleece` only if it's not followed by `.*?` any char zero or more times and a string `snow`.

```
(fleece)(?!.*?snow)
```

OR

Use word boundary `\b` if necessary.

```
\b(fleece)\b(?!.*?\bsnow\b)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/iZ5kC7/8)

Comment: but this `something(?!somethingelse)` checks for the immediate following.

Comment: You can remove the '?' after .* : `(fleece)(?!.*snow)`

Comment: Not really, the `?` makes it backtrack after each character after `fleece` before `snow` is encountered; removing it makes it backtrack after each character when working its way back from the end of the string to the word `snow` - the question is which way is the shorter one. If you can't say for sure that `snow` will be closer to `fleece` than to the end of the string, there's no good reason to leave the `?` in.

Comment: Couldn't see the wood for the trees. Thanks for answering. And the performance tip is useful, and not something I had considered. So, in my use case, the word snow WILL be closer to fleece than the end of the line, so it is better to make it non-greedy - i.e. (fleece)(?!.*?snow)